# Usage of %d does not output an integer

Tags: python, integer, string-formatting

I am finding it difficult to understand the `%d`format specifier. From the documentation, I know that it is a placeholder for integers but it doesn't seem to behave like that when I am using it:

```
>>> x=1
>>> x
1

>>> v = "%d" % x
>>> v
'1'
```

Can you please explain why it returns a string instead of an integer? It does the same thing as `%s`.

Comment: What outcome did you expect?

Comment: It formats the input (integer in this case) into a string.

Comment: @Junuxx: An integer instead of a string.

Comment: It seems like its work just like you described you thought it would.

Comment: `x` already is an integer, you don't need to do anything to make it an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` means "the string presentation of a signed integer decimal", so you get a string returned

Comment: %s would output the same thing, right? So, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: @NormalAnomaly: Different formatting options: Try `print "%04d %04s"% (1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

The %d is used to express the decimal form of the argument you pass formatted as a string. That is why `'%d' % 4` gives you `'4'`. If you do `'%d' % 0b101` you will get `'5'`. The same is true if you use hex. It gives you a decimal number formatted as a string.

Comment: And also "%s"%1.3 gives '1'

Comment: Oh yeah, good point. Its is the integer representation of the decimal (base 10) number.

Answer (score 0):

> v = "%d" % x

%d is the placeholder in a string for the variable. V is a string, as described by the quotes and the %d (which is a string representation of an integer), and x is therefore being cast into a string for the purposes of 'v'.